# "Alterando" de Jframe para JIntertalFrame

Tags: java, swing

Desenvolvi a primeira versão do meu projeto toda usando `Jframes`, mas no upgrade que estou fazendo resolvi mudar todas para um `JInternalFrame`. Dei uma olhada pela internet e vi que era possível, alterando as referencias dos arquivos `.JAVA` e `.Form` presentes no projeto.Mas não obtive sucesso. Há alguma maneira de fazer isso ou terei que refazer as telas todas no braço ?

Answer (score 2):

O arquivo `.form` não é gerado pelo java, e sim pela ferramenta do netbeans que cria telas. Esse arquivo ajuda a ferramenta a organizar a exibição da tela e dos componentes nela e suas definições, para que você possa visualizar a construção enquanto arrasta os componentes, sem precisar rodar o projeto.

Infelizmente não tem outro jeito, você terá que fazer manualmente, e e se alterar estes arquivos diretamente, provavelmente perderá parte(ou totalmente) da visualização na ferramenta. Esse é um dos grandes problemas pelos quais não utilizo essa ferramenta do netbeans, além de criar um "código sujo" e de difícil leitura e manutenção fora da IDE, ela torna o código dependente dela.